# Generative-Discriminative pairs: Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, naive-bayes, graphical-model, conditional-random-field

I'm trying to understand the something written in this [paper](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/papers/crf-tutorial.pdf).

At the bottom of page 7:

> This means that if the naive Bayes model  $$ p(y,\mathbf{x}) = p(y) \prod_k p(x_k|y) $$ is trained to
>   maximize the conditional likelihood, we recover the same classifier as
>   from logistic regression. Conversely, if the logistic regression model
>   $$p(y|\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{Z(\mathbf{x})} exp\left\{\sum_k \lambda_k f_k(y,\mathbf{x}) \right\} $$ is interpreted generatively, as in  $$p(y,\mathbf{x}) = \frac{exp\left\{\sum_k \lambda_k f_k(y,\mathbf{x}) \right\}}{\sum_{y', \mathbf{x}'}exp\left\{\sum_k \lambda_k f_k(y',\mathbf{x}') \right\}}$$ and is trained to
>   maximize the joint likelihood p(y, x), then we recover the same
>   classifier as from naive Bayes.

I'm having trouble seeing why this is.The next page goes on to say

> ...consider the family of naive Bayes distributions. This is a family
>   of joint distributions whose conditionals all take the "logistic
>   regression form". But there are many other joint models, some with
>   complex dependencies among $\mathbf{x}$, whose conditional
>   distributions also have the logistic regression form.

Aren't these statements contradictory? The conditioned-Bayes distributions are a subset of the logistic-regression-form distributions, so isn't it possible that maximizing over the latter yields a distribution not contained in the former?

Answer (score 1):

The $f_k(y,{\bf x})$ introduced at the top of page 5 are of a very special form that, crucially, is linear in ${\bf x}$ and so (dropping the $k$ subscript for a moment) can be written $f(y,{\bf x}) = \alpha_1^{(y)}x_1 + \ldots + \alpha_K^{(y)}x_K$ .  Exponentiating, that's just $\prod_k g(x_k|y)$, i.e. of Naïve-Bayes form.  Your second equation is the paper's (1.7), which is just the more transparent (1.6) in disguise.

You are quite right that if $f_k(y,{\bf x})$ were not of this special form then the mapping to NB would not be guaranteed.